# Unexpected end of JSON input error

Tags: reactjs, api

I have a reactjs page, which consumes an API:
...when tested via postman (GET request), the following results are rendered:

```
[
    {
        "clientI": "FedEx KinKOs"
    }
]
```

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {render} from "react-dom";
import './ClientInfo.css';

class ClientInfo extends Component {
    state = {
        data:[],
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos"
      };
   componentDidMount() {
    fetch(this.state.url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ data }));
  }

    render() {
        const { data } = this.state;
        data && console.log(data);
        return (
            <div>

                <div className="container">
                        <div className="clientContainer">
                        {data &&
                            data.map(item =>
                                <div>
                                    <span>{item.userId} </span>
                                    <span>{item.id} </span>
                                    <span>{item.title} </span>
                                </div>
                        )}
                        </div> 
            </div>  
          </div>
        );
      }
}
export default ClientInfo
```

...the error occurs on this line of the above code:
**.then(response => response.json())**

could I get some assistance as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation**

1. You are using `.then()` twice.
2. `response.json()` cannot be called, because you are getting an JSON object back from your endpoint. If there are'nt any callback functions inside, you cannot call the function `.json()` on it.
3. Setting the state with your `setState()` function will be totally enough.

**Solution**

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch(this.state.url).then(response => {
    this.setState({ response });
  });
}
```

Comment: Michael Czechowski - I applied the modification the componentDidMount function, but I get an error at : this.setState({ data });  ...the error saids: Failed to compile,  data' is not defined  no-undef. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Oh hell, sorry. My misstake, I will correct it. Did it help @user1724708?